# Select item from array within JSONB document using value from the same document

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I want to retrieve an item from an array in a JSONB document that looks roughly like this:

```
{
  meta: {
    selected: {id: 123}
  },
  items: [
    {id: 123, value: 'foo'},
    {id: 234, value: 'bar'},
    {id: 456, value: 'baz'},
  ]
}
```

I've tried something like this:

```sql
WITH items AS (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data#>items)
  FROM document
)
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE items @> document#>>'{meta, selected}'
```

I understand conceptually that the @> will return true if the items on the left contain the value on the right, but I'm unsure what the correct syntax for this is

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unnest the jsonb array with `jsonb_array_elements()` and a lateral join, and then do the filtering in the `where` clause:

```
select x.*
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'items') x(elt)
where x.elt ->> 'id' = t.data -> 'meta' -> 'selected' ->> 'id'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5cee5ed416c5299db53f829f5f843f0b)**:

```
| elt                         |
| :-------------------------- |
| {"id": 123, "value": "foo"} |
```

Note that you might as well use an `inner join lateral`:

```
select x.*
from mytable t
inner join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'items') x(elt)
    on x.elt ->> 'id' = t.data -> 'meta' -> 'selected' ->> 'id'
```